# SQL Filter on Table A using join on table B containing allowed values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, filtering

I have 2 tables with the following fields:

```
Employee:
- string: Name
- Integer: Age

AllowedAge:
- Integer: Age
```

The table AllowedAge contains either:

- all the ages that are permitted

OR

- the table is empty if all the ages are permitted (which makes sense because the table cannot contain an infinite number of allowed ages).

To query for the employees with the allowed age in a way that covers the case where AllowedAge is empty and we want to get all the Employees we can do:

```
select e.Name from Employee e 
left join AllowedAge aa on aa.Age = e.Age 
where (aa.Age IS NOT NULL) or ((select count(*) from AllowedAge) = 0)
```

Is there a better, more idiomatic way to achieve the same results? Speed of the query is the number one priority and both tables may contain 10s of millions of rows.

Comment: How does it perform when  you test it against millions of rows?

Comment: the speed of the query as I have shown it is adequate (good enough)

Comment: _both tables may contain 10s of millions of rows_ For a table of ages? This seems highly unlikely, inefficient, and simply foolish. Hopefully that is a mistake in your description.

Comment: Strange to put an age into the database, every year you need to update it

Comment: Based on your explanation, this smells like some kind of unnecessary over engineering, perhaps consider the real value of whatever you've built here. What are you really trying to validate? Would just entering a birth date be a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

Move the conditions to the `where` clause.  I would recommend:

```
select e.*
from employee e
where not exists (select 1 from AllowedAge aa) or
      exists (select 1
              from AllowedAge aa
              where aa.age = e.age
             );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my this seems much slower than my original query

Comment: @mnrtyrpt123 . . . Interesting.  I wouldn't expect it to be *slower*.  An index on `AllowedAge(age)` should fix the performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right direction, just need to use `OUTER APPLY` and `OR` condition in the `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT e.Name 
FROM Employee e 
OUTER APPLY(SELECT COUNT(*) tot FROM AllowedAge) t
LEFT JOIN AllowedAge aa on aa.Age = e.Age 
WHERE (t.tot = 0 OR aa.Age = e.Age)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that doesn't seem to work when I try: all the rows are returned, no filtering occurs

Comment: @mnrtyrpt123 you are right, I have done some changes please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for IF ELSE logic.

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM AllowedAge) -- all ages allowed 
BEGIN
    SELECT e.Name from Employee e 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    select e.Name from Employee e 
    inner join AllowedAge aa on aa.Age = e.Age
END
```